# TYPO3 doesn't hide the Bootstrap hamburger menu after closing it

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, typo3, navbar, typo3-10.x

I have a problem with my navigation in the mobile view. The menu works fine when it is open, but when I close it the whole menu moves next to the navigation bar.

**Here is a pic of the problem:**
[image: The Problem]

**Before:**
[image: closed menu]

Could it be that I forgot to add a bootstrap file or is it a TYPO3 problem?

Thanks a lot already

Comment: I would assume it is a problem of your Javascript and/or CSS. on Click the JS should change classes so the menu should be hidden. Either the class-changing does not work or the CSS for hiding is not active: check for JS-errors, then check for CSS styles (missing or overwritten)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ Thank you! removed my customize CSS file to check if I overwrote anything. After removing the whole file it works again! Now I check each class of the file separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. i overwrote a class in the CSS file.

```
#mainnavigation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex: none;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: auto;
}
```